# Hadoop query, dates, loops, BASH or Java

Tags: java, bash, hadoop, hive, hue

I'm pretty new to Hadoop, Linux, and haven't coded in Java for over 15 years, so am typically only using Hue to run queries.  My issue is that I'm trying to run a basic select query over 12 months worth of data, however, due to the dataset huge size and read thresholds being applied this query will always fail.  Therefore I need to run this same query per week/month, insert the results into a pre-existing table, and then aggregate them to my final 12 month period.

Original query: -

```
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM foo
    WHERE local_date >= '2013-09-01'
    AND local_date < '2014-09-01'
```

Possible new script (PLSQL format): -

```
    DECLARE dtStart DATE;
    DECLARE dtEnd DATE;

    SET dtStart = (CURRENT_DATE - 1 YEAR) + 1 DAYS - DAY(CURRENT_DATE);
    SET dtEnd = CURRENT_DATE + 1 DAYS - DAY(CURRENT_DATE);

    WHILE dtStart < dtEnd THEN DO

            INSERT INTO test
            SELECT col1, col2, col3
            FROM foo
            WHERE local_date >= dtStart
            AND local_date < dtStart + 7 DAYS;

            IF dtStart = dtEnd THEN
                    SET dtStart = dtStart + 1 DAYS;
            ELSEIF dtEnd - dtStart < 7 THEN
                    SET dtStart = dtStart + (dtEnd - dtStart) DAYS;
            ELSE
                    SET dtStart = dtStart + 7 DAYS;
            END IF;
    END WHILE;

    SELECT col1, col2, SUM(col3)
    FROM test
    GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

I've been told that this is not possible in Hue.  Is that correct?  Can this be done within BASH or do I need to create some Java code?  As you can see I'd also like the dates to be dynamic, however, I believe the date functions within Hadoop are unable to do this.

Any help would be appreciated, particularly examples in BASH or Jave which would do something like and/or advice on further reading.

Comment: Please, post the fail message

Comment: Hi @nosmo, the message is simply stating that the number of reads required (18750) is over the limit (5000).  This limit (I have no control over it) was much higher previously so I had no problem.  I have to loop the same query into shorter time periods and then aggregate afterwards, but I'm unsure on the best method as I'm new to Hadoop.  The script example I supplied will work fine in PL/SQL, but can I do this in Hue?  If not, which will be best going forward, BASH or Java or what, particularly if other users will end up running this or perhaps I can get it scheduled to run automatically?

Comment: If the limitation is with the limit being set then a simple bash script to generate different dates and calling it on the query will do the job. As i know Hue doesn't have that support. Please tell me if you need the exact bash.

Answer (score 1):

Hue sometime fails with queries involving huge amounts of data. However instead of doing a select query redirect the output of your query for whole one year into another table and see it works.

Alternatively, you can run the uery using Hive command line client. Please try there once and see if it works.

You can use it from shell like this:

> hive -e "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM foo WHERE local_date >=
>   '2013-09-01' AND local_date < '2014-09-01'"

Comment: Hi @Amar, as I mentioned before the failure is imply down to a threshold set by my IT dept (I have no control over it). It was much higher previously so I had no problem. I am trying to do exactly what you suggested, but I have to loop the same query into shorter time periods and then aggregate afterwards, but I'm unsure on the best method as I'm new to Hadoop which is why I suggested the script example. Can I do this in Hue? If not, what is best going forward, BASH or Java or what, particularly if other users will end up running this?